# opencart cart load issue

Tags: php, html, opencart2.x

I am using opencart version 2.0.1.1 and I have modified common cart.tpl according to my requirement I meant alignment so after I changed if I add any product to cart means it will show success message and even product is adding to cart but when I click on cart button it is showing "ul" but inside ul, li is there that is not displaying and If I load page means it will show products in the cart otherwise not showing.

Please any one help me on this.

Below is cart.tpl,

```
<a id="cart_close_1">X</a>
<div id="cart" class="btn-group btn-block">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-inverse btn-block btn-lg dropdown-toggle animate"><i class="crtIcon animAll"></i><!--  <span id="cart-total"><?php echo $text_items; ?></span> --></button>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right <?php echo $class_cart; ?> " id="remove_cart">
  <?php if ($products || $vouchers) { ?>
    <li><div class="cart-container cf">
      <?php $count=0;
        foreach ($products as $product) { $count++;
         ?>
        <div class="qckimg-vd">
          <div class="quck-img">
            <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
            <!-- <img src="image/10-cm-blue-sparklers.jpg" alt="10-cm-blue-sparklers"> -->
            <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-thumbnail" /></a>
            <?php }?>
          </div><!-- quck-img -->
          <div class="proqty">
            <div class="nobTn">
              <button type="button" class="btn-number" data-type="minus" data-field="input-quantity_<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" data-price="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" class="min_order_amount" data-value="<?php echo "3400";?>"/>
                <span>-</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="quantity" min="1" max="100" value="1" size="2" id="input-quantity_<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" class="pro_class" data-id="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" maxlength="3" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
            <div class="nobTn">
              <button type="button" class="btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="input-quantity_<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" data-price="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
                <span>+</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none">Input digits (0 - 9)</span>
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="p_id" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
            </div>
        </div><!-- qckimg-vd -->
        <div class="shoping-cart-desc">
          <h2><?php echo $product['name']; ?></h2>
          <h3><?php echo $product['attribute_value']; ?></h3>
          <h4><!-- <span class="qty_total <?php echo "count_".$count;?>" data-count="<?php echo $count;?>"><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?> X </span> --><span class="orgprice count_total"  id="or_price_<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" data-actprice="<?php echo str_replace( ',', '', $product['price'] ); ?>"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span></h4>
          <!-- <a href="">Remove</a> -->
          <a href="javascript:;" onclick="cart.remove('<?php echo $product['key']; ?>');" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>">Remove</a>
        </div><!-- shoping-cart-desc -->
        <?php }?>
      </div><!-- cart-container -->
      <div class="sub-tot">
          <?php $count=0;foreach($products as $product){$count++;?>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php foreach ($totals as $total) {?>
          <?php }?>
          <div class="cf">
              <h4 class="lft">Subtotal (<?php echo $count;?> item(s))</h4>
              <h4 class="rght total_price" data-type="minus plus" data-total="<?php echo str_replace( ',', '', $total['text'] ); ?>"><?php echo $total['text']; ?></h4>
              <!-- <h4 class="lft">Shipping</h4>
              <h4 class="rght">NA</h4> -->
          </div>
          <div class="total cf">
            <h4 class="lft">Total</h4>
            <h4 class="rght total_price"><?php echo $total['text']; ?></h4>
          </div>
      </div><!-- sub-tot -->
      <div class="shp-btns">
        <a class="chckout" href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>">Checkout</a>
      </div><!-- shp-btns -->
      <div class="min-ordr">
        <h3>Minimum order amount should be
        Rs.3400 to checkout.</h3>
      </div><!-- min-ordr -->
      </li>
    <?php }else{?>
      <li style="height:auto;">
         <p class="text-center tCeTxt"><?php echo $text_empty; ?></p>
      </li>
  <?php }?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

js cart function,

```
'add': function(product_id, quantity) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#cart > button').button('loading');
            },
            success: function(json) { 
                var error_msg = false;
                $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();

                $('#cart > button').button('reset');

                //For Showing Product Stock Error
                if (json['error_warning']) { 
                    error_msg = true;
                    $('#cart_id').parent().before('<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['error_warning'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button></div>');
                    $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
                }

                if (json['redirect'] && error_msg == false) { 
                    location = json['redirect'];
                }

                if (json['success']) { 
                    $('#cart_id').parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button></div>');

                    $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                    /*$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');*/

                    $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

Controller,

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonCart extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('common/cart');

        // Totals
        $this->load->model('extension/extension');

        $total_data = array();
        $total = 0;
        $taxes = $this->cart->getTaxes();

        // Display prices
        if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
            $sort_order = array();

            $results = $this->model_extension_extension->getExtensions('total');

            foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
                $sort_order[$key] = $this->config->get($value['code'] . '_sort_order');
            }

            array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $results);

            foreach ($results as $result) {

                if ($this->config->get($result['code'] . '_status')) {
                    $this->load->model('total/' . $result['code']);

                    $this->{'model_total_' . $result['code']}->getTotal($total_data, $total, $taxes);
                }
            }

            $sort_order = array();

            foreach ($total_data as $key => $value) {
                $sort_order[$key] = $value['sort_order'];
            }

            array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $total_data);
        }

        $data['text_empty'] = $this->language->get('text_empty');
        $data['text_cart'] = $this->language->get('text_cart');
        $data['text_checkout'] = $this->language->get('text_checkout');
        $data['text_recurring'] = $this->language->get('text_recurring');
        $data['text_shipping'] = $this->language->get('text_shipping');
        $data['text_minimum_ord_amount'] = $this->language->get('text_minimum_ord_amount');
        $data['text_items'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_items'), $this->cart->countProducts() + (isset($this->session->data['vouchers']) ? count($this->session->data['vouchers']) : 0), $this->currency->format($total));
        $data['text_loading'] = $this->language->get('text_loading');

        $data['button_remove'] = $this->language->get('button_remove');

        $this->load->model('tool/image');
        $this->load->model('tool/upload');

        $data['products'] = array();

        foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {
            if ($product['image']) {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_cart_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_cart_height'));
            } else {
                $image = '';
            }

            $option_data = array();

            foreach ($product['option'] as $option) {
                if ($option['type'] != 'file') {
                    $value = $option['value'];
                } else {
                    $upload_info = $this->model_tool_upload->getUploadByCode($option['value']);

                    if ($upload_info) {
                        $value = $upload_info['name'];
                    } else {
                        $value = '';
                    }
                }

                $option_data[] = array(
                    'name'  => $option['name'],
                    'value' => (utf8_strlen($value) > 20 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 20) . '..' : $value),
                    'type'  => $option['type']
                );
            }

            // Display prices
            if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
            } else {
                $price = false;
            }

            // Display prices
            if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                $total = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')) * $product['quantity']);
            } else {
                $total = false;
            }
            //For Getting Pieces/Items per box
            $product_attribute = $this->model_catalog_product->getSpecificProductAttribute($product['product_id']);
            $attribute_value = '';
            if($product_attribute) {
                $attribute_value = $product_attribute['text'];
            }
            $data['products'][] = array(
                'key'       => $product['key'],
                'product_id'=> $product['product_id'],
                'thumb'     => $image,
                'name'      => $product['name'],
                'model'     => $product['model'],
                'option'    => $option_data,
                'recurring' => ($product['recurring'] ? $product['recurring']['name'] : ''),
                'quantity'  => $product['quantity'],
                'price'     => $price,
                'attribute_value'=> $attribute_value,
                'total'     => $total,
                'href'      => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id'])
            );
        }

        // Gift Voucher
        $data['vouchers'] = array();

        if (!empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) {
            foreach ($this->session->data['vouchers'] as $key => $voucher) {
                $data['vouchers'][] = array(
                    'key'         => $key,
                    'description' => $voucher['description'],
                    'amount'      => $this->currency->format($voucher['amount'])
                );
            }
        }

        $data['totals'] = array();

        foreach ($total_data as $result) {
            $data['totals'][] = array(
                'title' => $result['title'],
                'text'  => $this->currency->format($result['value']),
            );
        }

        $data['cart'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');
        $data['checkout'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', 'SSL');

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/cart.tpl')) {
            return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/cart.tpl', $data);
        } else {
            return $this->load->view('default/template/common/cart.tpl', $data);
        }
    }

    public function info() {
        $this->response->setOutput($this->index());
    }
}
```